# Developing in Adobe CQ5 with jetty?

Tags: jetty, aem

We use maven to deploy the code changes to cq interner server / CRX Lite and the problem here is that it `takes long time` where the changes itself is often only one line code.

Has somebody experience with `CQ5 with jetty` and can give me a good Guide?

Comment: No experience with jetty here, but other options that are faster than a maven buil: using VLT (http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html) or AEM Developer Tools (https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-eclipse-developer-tools)

Comment: @Thomas I have installed aem-eclipse-developer-tools plugin and started my project in AEM perspective. my question is how to use aem to deploy from file system to crx lite / cq server? I could not find any Guide online

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't have time yet to check these dev tools by myself. I was only told that they exist during a dev training at Adobe. So I can't give you any support, but I thought it should synchronize on save. The only documentation I found was linked on the github page: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dev-tools/aem-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

am not sure i understand the relationship with jetty (which ships as servlet container of latter versions of AEM/CQ5), but will answer to the code deployment part:

- deploying a full content package (full content) should be done using
  [maven-content-package plugin](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin/) for smaller deployments of content,
- when you can't use integrated dev environments like sling eclipse dev
  tools, i'd suggest you use the excellent [repo](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/tools/tree/master/repo) command that basically zips the current  folder and deploy it. I'm using it as an external tool command of intellij and it's really fast.
- finally, if the deployment you're referring to is osgi deployment, maven sling plugin can help you with that (will still compile/package the whole osgi bundle though)